# Prepared Statement doesn't recognize any parameters on Postgres JS binding

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, node-postgres

I'm trying to make an update for multiple rows at once.
For this, I'm making the folowing prepared statement :

```
WITH new_values (id, data, email) AS (
  VALUES ($1, $2, $3), ($4, $5, $6), ($7, $8, $9), ($10, $11, $12)
)
UPDATE prospects
  SET 
    data = new_values.data,
    email = new_values.email
  FROM new_values
  WHERE
    prospects.id = new_values.id
  RETURNING *
```

But I'm getting the following error :

```
error: bind message supplies 12 parameters, but prepared statement "prospects-multi-update" requires 0
api-prospects_1       |     at Connection.parseE (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:546:11)
api-prospects_1       |     at Connection.parseMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:371:19)
api-prospects_1       |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:114:22)
api-prospects_1       |     at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
api-prospects_1       |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
api-prospects_1       |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
api-prospects_1       |     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
api-prospects_1       |     at TCP.onread (net.js:581:20)
```

I have tried different queries (with `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`) but it does the same.

It's working only on straight `INSERT INTO` queries.

---

### EDIT

Here is the code calling this query :
(I have remove the string generation functions since it's not very useful)

```
const upsertValues = async (entities) => {
  if (entities.length === 0) return []

  const client = pool.connect()

  const values = [...]
  const variables = [...]
  const setStatements = [...]

  const res = await client.query({
    name: `${resourceName}-multi-update`,
    test: `
      WITH new_values (id, ${columns}) AS (
        VALUES ${variables}
      )
      UPDATE prospects
        SET ${setStatements}
        FROM new_values
        WHERE
          prospects.id = new_values.id
        RETURNING *
    `,
    values: flatten(values),
  })

  return res.row || []
}
```

Comment: You should include the code you used for executing the query. Most likely the problem is somewhere in there.

Comment: @vitaly-t I have edited with the code on the call site. I have juste removed the generation of the diferent parts of the query since it's just string manipulation and the generated query is corect.

Comment: The query must be passed in as property `text`, and not `test`.

Comment: @vitaly-t Yeah I have found out ... Damn dynamic typing.

Comment: @vitaly-t You can answer the question if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to property `text` of the prepared statement being misnamed as `test`, so the engine cannot even find the query string.